# re install windows 7, should I need product key

Tags: windows-7, reinstall

I want to re-install my windows 7 OEM, so that I can delete my old employees files, software, etc. As per [this link](http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-reinstall-windows-7-easily-step-by-step-guide/), I can do re-install windows 7, my doubt is If I do this reinstallation would I be prompt to enter product key or not If so can I enter same key that I have used before.

Answer (score 5):

> ### Will I ever need to activate Windows on my computer again?
>
> Maybe. You might have to activate Windows again if:
>
> - You make a significant hardware change to your computer, such as upgrading the hard disk and memory at the same time. If a major hardware change requires activating Windows again, you'll be notified and will have three days to activate Windows.
> - You reinstall Windows. In this case, you'll have 30 days to activate Windows again.
>
> If you have to activate Windows again on the same computer, you don't need to buy a new product key. For more information, see [Activate Windows 7 on this computer](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/activate-windows#1TC=windows-7).

­

> A simple solution to get round the need to activate when you reinstall Windows is backing up the required activation files and information from the old install, and then restoring it when the new install is complete.
>
> [Advanced Tokens Manager](http://joshcellsoftwares.com/products/advancedtokensmanager/) is a free and portable utility to backup and restore the activation information for any version of Windows Vista, 7 and Server 2008/2011 with a couple of clicks. It also supports Office 2010 activation backup and restore, not any previous versions like 2007/2003 though. What it does is back up the product key and a file called `tokens.dat` that holds the activation information for Windows and also Office 2010.

## References

- [Activating Windows: frequently asked questions](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/activating-windows-faq#1TC=windows-7)
- [Backup and Restore Activation Files for Windows 7, Vista and Office 2010](http://www.raymond.cc/blog/backup-restore-activation-files-windows-7-vista-office-2010/)

Answer (score 3):

A quick Google of the problem and I found that you are able to use the same key again, but only if there are no other systems currently using that key. So you should be in the clear.

Comment: Well duh. If it is a regular CoA then it is not legal to use it on an other computer at the same time. So there will (should) be no other systems currently using that key.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to reinstall Windows 7, then do so.  The product key on the COA (Certificate of Authenticity) sticker on the box is the one you should use if prompted for one.  It's POSSIBLE if the PC is a major brand (Dell, HP, etc) that Windows will auto-active when re-installed with a Windows 7 disk included with the PC.

Product keys are NOT use once and stop.  They can be activated multiple times on the hardware they came with.  In the event there is a problem with Activation, you can call MS and they should help you activate over the phone.

Bottom line - if this computer was purchased with Windows 7 and purchased from a reputable vendor, then you should have problem reinstalling 10 times if you need and activating each time.